# How to display speed and change the speed of an object in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic, traffic-simulation

New to anylogic (or coding as a whole) and i have a few questions.

i have created a car agent and it has 4 different car types and im wondering on how i can change the speed of these car types once it is ran. i also would like to display the speed of the agent i have created in statistics so that i can view the mean speed of the different car types.

i can already display the statistics using getSpeed() but i think that it is displaying the speed of the main agent instead of the agent i created. i also tried to use setPrefferedSpeed as i see in other questions but it errors saying undefined variable

Comment: best do all (!) the step-by-step tutorials,they cover these basics and many more. See https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html